Isolating Projects for Multiple Users in Node-RED Deployed on Kubernetes EKS with EFS Volume
I'm working on a project using Node-RED deployed on the Kubernetes platform (EKS), with data volume mounted to EFS and ingress load balancing configured.
We are setting up version control for the Node-RED flows using Bitbucket.
I have multiple users like admin and test configured in the settings.js file with separate
credentials:
  adminAuth: {
    type: "credentials",
    users: [{
      username: "admin",
      password: "$2b$08$hashedPassword1",
      permissions: "*"
    },
    {
      username: "test",
      password: "$2b$08$hashedPassword2",
      permissions: "*"
    }]
  },


Both users can log in successfully. However, I've encountered the following issue:
When the admin user creates or clones a project from Bitbucket in their Node-RED session, the same project and flows are visible and editable by the test user in their browser session.
I want to isolate each user’s workspace, ensuring that projects and flows are independent between users (admin and test).
My Deployment Details:
Node-RED is deployed on AWS EKS.
Flows and settings are stored on an EFS volume.
Projects feature is enabled in the settings.js file, and the version control is connected to Bitbucket.
Here is my relevant settings.js configuration:
module.exports = {
  flowFile: 'flows.json',
  projects: {
    enabled: true,
    workflow: {
      mode: "manual"
    }
  },
  functionGlobalContext: {
    fs: require('fs'),
    path: require('path')
  }
}

What I Need:
How can I configure Node-RED to isolate user sessions so that the admin user and test user can work on their respective projects without interference?
Is there a recommended approach to handle multi-user project isolation in a team environment with Git synchronization?
What I’ve Tried:
Enabling projects in settings.js and setting up Bitbucket integration.
Using EFS for storage, but this seems to cause shared access to flows.
Any guidance or suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

As I mentioned when you raised this on the Node-RED Slack.
This is not possible, a single instance of Node-RED just can't work this way.
A single instance of Node-RED only has ONE set of flows (or project) and this is accessible to ALL users that connect to that instance.
If you want separation between users you MUST run separate instances of Node-RED.
There are projects that will manage multiple users and instances required for the type of deployment you are looking for. One example of this is FlowFuse (Full disclosure I work for FlowFuse)
